# Delete a file even if it is running

Tags: vb.net, file, process

I need to remove a file even if it is used by a running process.
Firstly, of course the process needs to be shut down, and after that the file should be deleted, if it exists.

I'm using the following code:

***Sample:***

```
Dim Processes() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("test")
    For Each Process As Process In Processes
        Process.Kill()
    Next
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(C:\ProgramFiles\Test\test.exe)
```

I tried the code above, it does not work, file is still running and also it is not removed! Can you please provide a reliable solution to this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Does `GetProcessesByName("test")` definitely get the process you want it to? If you manually kill the process in Task Manager, can you then manually delete the file?

Comment: Yes, I can delete the file if I kill it from the Task Manager, however I want my application to first kill the process(only if it is running) , and after that, delete the file. The "test" was only provided as a sample. It would be replaced by the file name I want to kill and delete.

Comment: Does `GetProcessesByName("someFilename")` definitely get the process you want it to?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: If you make the code pause for a couple of seconds, `Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)`, can it then delete the file? Like there is a small delay between you killing it in Task Manager and then deleting it.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion did really worked! This issue has been successfully resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may take a little while for the after-effects of `Process.Kill()` to complete.

If you add a delay between the Kill command and the File.Delete, such as `Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)`, it may be sufficient for the latter to complete.

A more robust solution might involve repeatedly attempting to delete the file, up to some reasonable number of tries, with a small time delay between attempts.